# Bind second UITableView on RowClick of first UITableView in the same UIViewController - ios Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, uiviewcontroller

I have two `UITableView` in the same `UIViewController`.
tblView1 & tblView2.

Both TableViews are bringing data dynamically.
Now my problem is: I want to load data in tblView2 on the basis of SelectedRow from tblView1.

For Example, when I select a company name from tblView1, then tblView2 needs to populate the Cars made by that company.

I have rowIndex of my first table (tblView1), but i can't bind my tblView2 from the RowSelected Method of tblView1.
I need help in binding my tblView2. **How can i do this?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Tables
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }
        public ViewController()
        {
            //tblView2.Source = new CompanyModelsSource();

            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            if (tblView1 != null)
            {
                tblView1.Source = new CarModelsSource();

            }
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }

    class CompanyModelsSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        private List<Companies> _Companies;
        NSString _cellID = new NSString("TableCell");

        public CompanyModelsSource()
        {
            _Companies = CompanyTableSource.AllCompany();
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            // tell the TableView how many rows to create
            return _Companies.Count;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        //I can't access my tblView2 in this method. So where i can bind my other UITableView?

            UILabel lblTotalFacilities = new UILabel();
            lblTotalFacilities.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
            lblTotalFacilities.Frame = new CGRect(305, 200, 1024, 400);

            ViewController vc = new ViewController();
            vc.View.AddSubview(lblTotalFacilities);
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Company currentCompany = _Companies[indexPath.Row];

            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellID) as CompanyTableCell;
            if (cell == null) { cell = new CompanyTableCell(_cellID); }

            cell.UpdateCellControlsWithAuditData(currentCompany.Name);

            return cell;
        }
    }

    public class CompanyTableSource
    {
        public CompanyTableSource()
        {
        }

        public static List<Companies> AllCompany()
        {
            CompanyCollection CC = null;

            string path1 = path + "Companies.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CompanyCollection));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path1);
            CC = (CompanyCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();

            List<Companies> comp = CC.CompanyCollection.Cast<Companies>().ToList();
            return comp;
        }
    }

    public class CompanyTableCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        UILabel nameLabel;
        public CompanyTableCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;
            ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(54, 194, 36);

            var newFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12);

            nameLabel = new UILabel();
            nameLabel.Font = newFont;

            ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { nameLabel });
        }


        public void UpdateCellControlsWithAuditData(string Name)
        {
            nameLabel.Text = Name;

        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            nameLabel.Frame = new CGRect(10, 0, 350, 33);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: TablesViewController]

Comment: In the CompanyTableSource class create a public Event and subscribe to it from the ViewController then in the RowSelected method of that DataSource raise the event. In the ViewController you will have an event handler that will be notified and there you will be able to fetch the information you need of the second tableView based on the RowSelected of the first tableview. (don't have VS here to show you code, hope this gives you the idea at least)

Comment: I can provide you my TeamViewer if you can help me please.

Comment: @apineda or if you can give me a link to some example?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. Created everything in a single file for simplicity.

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController() : base("ViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var companySource = new CompanyTableSource();
        tblView1.Source = companySource;

        companySource.ItemSelected += OnCompanyItemSelected;
    }

    // This will handle the ItemSelected event
    // Here you will retrieve the data for the second UITableView
    void OnCompanyItemSelected(object sender, Company e)
    {
        // you can do it this way
        tblView2.Source = new CarTableSource(e.Id);

        List<Car> cars = GetCarsByCompanyId(e.Id);

        // or this way
        tblView2.Source = new CarTableSource(cars);
    }

    List<Car> GetCarsByCompanyId(int id)
    {
        // Your logic to get the data goes here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CompanyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    // You can use the whole object or just an integer (companyId)
    public event EventHandler<Company> ItemSelected;

    public IList<Company> Items { get; private set; } = new List<Company>();

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var item = Items[indexPath.Row];

        ItemSelected?.Invoke(this, item);
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // Do your implementation
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Items.Count;
    }
}

public class CarTableSource : UITableViewSource
{

    public IList<Car> Items { get; private set; } = new List<Car>();

    public CarTableSource(int companyId)
    { 
        // Get your data based on the companyId
    }

    // Or pass in the data already retrieved (I prefer this method)
    public CarTableSource(IList<Car> cars)
    {
        Items = cars;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // Do your implementation
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Items.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me in a different way. I tried to bind the `UITableView` in the Event, but this didn't worked, then i created `UITableView` Dynamically in the Event and then provided him source and it worked. :-) 
Thanks,

Can you please look at another question of me about Xamarin?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/41833049/4728323